# Add property to the top level of a jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) I can figure out how to replace or add a value at from an existing property

```
{"example":123}
```

```
UPDATE mytable
SET jsoncolumn = jsonb_set(jsoncolumn, '{example}', '"string123"')
WHERE id = 1;
```

```
{"example":"string123"}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to insert a property at the top level (beside a sibling)

```
{"example":123}
```

```
{"example":123,"property-to-add":"value"}
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this (given that the actual object is pretty large)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the new key/value pair:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET jsoncolumn = jsoncolumn || '{"property-to-add": "value"}'
WHERE id = 1;
```

If `property-to-add` already exists, it will be replaced.